# convert string to number and vice versa in C (NOT C++)

Tags: c, string, numbers

Is there a way to convert a string to a number and vice versa in C? I know that I can use iostream in C++ and use atoi() or sprintf() etc.. I want to know if there's a way to accomplish this in C without the use of streams. The only solution I see at this point is to create my own function, unless someone knows an already existing and proven solution.

Basically, is there a C equivalent to C++'s atoi() and sprintf()  ?

Comment: Both of those are C: [atoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) and [sprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: `atoi()` and `sprintf()` are C functions. Better than using `atoi()` is using `strto(u)l(l)()`, however.

Comment: The standard C library is apparently an ancient and unknown art in the modern world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of these are C functions:

- `atoi` is in `stdlib.h`
- `sprintf` is in `stdio.h`

And since these are included as part of C, neither require C++ streams.

Comment: It appears I wasn't looking at a very good C reference. Or just looking in the wrong places. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... according to http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdlib.h/atoi - `atoi is considered to be deprecated by strtol`. So he should use `strtol` instead of `atoi`?